# Size block-DIV based on absolutely positioned sub-DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a container DIV which contains several block-DIVS. Every block-DIV contains SPAN items with values. The blocks have the same WIDTH as the container and are floating in the container, so it looks as if they are 'rows'. The SPAN items are floating inside the block-DIV.

Every block has a fixed height of 25px. **I want to increase the height of a block-DIV (automatically) based on the contents of a SPAN item (.bigger in the example).** However it doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions?

**UPDATED CODE**

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>



<div id="VandaagLijst" class="Container">        
        <div
        id="8378" 
        class="WorkorderBlock" 
    size="print"
        >

        <span class="Workorder">A100032</span>
        <span class="Pn">3800702-1</span>
        <span class="Description">Gas Turbine Engine 131-9B</span>
        <span class="LastTask">Visual Inspection</span>
        <span class="Status">Open</span>
        <span class="Remarks">Test</span>
        <span class="RemarksAction"><img src="/Content/note.png" title="Add remark" alt="Add remark" /></span>
        <span class="Shipdate">30-04-2008</span>
        <span class="ActualShipdate">30-04-2008</span>

        <span class="Rek">-29</span>
        <span class="Shortages">4132159-1 (SV): ""<br />4132202-4 (SV): ""</span>


        </div>

        <div
        id="9142" 
        class="WorkorderBlock" 
        statustype="go"
    size="print"
        >

        <span class="Workorder">S100580</span>
        <span class="Pn">3616960-2</span>
        <span class="Description">Cooling Fan Assembly</span>
        <span class="LastTask">Disassembly</span>
        <span class="Status">Open</span>
        <span class="Remarks">Test</span>
        <span class="RemarksAction"><img src="/Content/note.png" title="Add remark" alt="Add remark" /></span>
        <span class="Shipdate">09-06-2008</span>
        <span class="ActualShipdate">09-06-2008</span>

        <span class="Rek">-365</span>
        <span class="Shortages">3616967-1 (SV): ""</span>


        </div>

        <div
        id="9278" 
        class="WorkorderBlock" 
        statustype="delay"
    size="print"
        >

        <span class="Workorder">A100063</span>
        <span class="Pn">3800550-1</span>
        <span class="Description">Gas Turbine Engine Assembly -500</span>
        <span class="LastTask">DMM Readout</span>
        <span class="Status">Quoted - Hold</span>
        <span class="Remarks">Test</span>
        <span class="RemarksAction"><img src="/Content/note.png" title="Add remark" alt="Add remark" /></span>
        <span class="Shipdate">18-07-2008</span>
        <span class="ActualShipdate">18-07-2008</span>
        <span class="Rek">8</span>

        <span class="Shortages">160488-2 (SV): ""<br />160536-1 (SV): ""<br />2704442-4 (SV): ""<br />3101768-1 (NE): ""<br />3202854-1 (SV): ""<br />3283076-5 (SV): ""<br />3503876-6 (SV): ""<br />3505814-3 (OH): ""<br />362-509-9002 (NE): ""<br />3804011-8 (SV): ""<br />3805034-8 (SV): ""<br />3810630-10 (NE): ""<br />3810727-6 (SV): ""<br />3810730-1 (SV): ""<br />3822341-4 (SV): ""<br />3822353-1 (SV): ""<br />3822360-1 (NE): ""<br />3822364-1 (NE): ""<br />3822483-1 (SV): ""<br />3822615-1 (NE): ""<br />3826919-4 (SV): ""<br />3826981-2 (NE): ""<br />3827140-2 (SV): ""<br />3827141-2 (SV): ""<br />3827164-4 (SV): ""<br />3827191-1 (SV): ""<br />3827315-2 (SV): ""<br />3830444-1 (SV): ""<br />3840124-3 (NE): ""<br />3840130-1 (NE): ""<br />3840137-1 (NE): ""<br />3840206-1 (NE): ""<br />3840278-1 (NE): ""<br />3840279-1 (NE): ""<br />3840280-3 (NE): ""<br />3842151-3 (NE): ""<br />3842155-3 (SV): ""<br />3842160-5 (NE): ""<br />3844398-1 (NE): ""<br />3844460-2 (NE): ""<br />3844467-1 (NE): ""<br />3844469-2 (SV): ""<br />3844471-6 (NE): ""<br />3844481-2 (NE): ""<br />3844488-3 (SV): ""<br />3844495-1 (SV): ""<br />3844496-1 (NE): ""<br />3844514-2 (NE): ""<br />3844515-2 (NE): ""<br />3844602-5 (NE): ""<br />3844607-1 (NE): ""<br />3844608-1 (NE): ""<br />3844611-1 (NE): ""<br />3844612-1 (NE): ""<br />3844680-1 (NE): ""<br />3844854-1 (NE): ""<br />3844900-1 (SV): ""<br />3844910-1 (NE): ""<br />3862212-3 (NE): ""<br />3862285-1 (NE): ""<br />3870222-1 (SV): ""<br />3876212-1 (SV): ""<br />3876214-2 (NE): ""<br />3881248-2 (NE): ""<br />3881259-2 (NE): ""<br />3881334-1 (NE): ""<br />3881623-1 (SV): ""<br />3883327-1 (NE): ""<br />3883453-1 (OH): ""<br />3883499-2 (NE): ""<br />3884966-1 (NE): ""<br />3888267-7 (NE): ""<br />3888364-3 (SV): ""<br />4131000-6 (SV): ""<br />525-121-9003 (NE): ""<br />525-203-9006 (NE): ""<br />525-533-9005 (NE): ""<br />73563-53 (NE): ""<br />968214-6 (SV): ""<br />M25988-2-011 (NE): ""<br />M25988-2-012 (NE): ""<br />M25988-2-013 (NE): ""<br />M25988-2-908 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-012 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-013 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-014 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-016 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-017 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-019 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-023 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-038 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-109 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-110 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-112 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-118 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-128 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-152 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-153 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-158 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-238 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-280 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-906 (NE): ""<br />M83248/1-011 (NE): ""<br />MS21043-3 (NE): ""<br />MS21043-4 (NE): ""<br />MS35769-10 (NE): ""<br />MS35769-6 (NE): ""<br />MS51843-25SS (NE): ""<br />MS9385-906 (NE): ""<br />MS9386-011 (NE): ""<br />MS9386-109 (NE): ""<br />MS9386-258 (NE): ""<br />MS9489-04 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-04 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-05 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-06 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-07 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-10 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-12 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-17 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-18 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-19 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-19 (NE): ""<br />MS9556-21 (NE): ""<br />MS9557-10 (NE): ""<br />MS9557-15 (NE): ""<br />MS9565-32 (NE): ""<br />MS9705-06 (NE): ""<br />NAS1102E3-7 (NE): ""<br />S8990-276 (NE): ""<br />S8990-281 (NE): ""<br />SL4-280 (NE): ""<br />SL4-280 (NE): ""</span>



        </div>

        <div
        id="9389" 
        class="WorkorderBlock" 
        statustype="delay"
    size="print"
        >
        <span class="Workorder">S100598</span>
        <span class="Pn">3804011-8</span>

        <span class="Description">LOAD COMPRESSOR</span>
        <span class="LastTask">Repair</span>
        <span class="Status">Cust-Delayed </span>
        <span class="Remarks">Test</span>
        <span class="RemarksAction"><img src="/Content/note.png" title="Add remark" alt="Add remark" /></span>
        <span class="Shipdate">31-12-2009</span>
        <span class="ActualShipdate">31-12-2009</span>
        <span class="Rek">539</span>
        <span class="Shortages">3610875-32 (NE): ""<br />3822343-1 (NE): ""<br />3826927-3 (NE): ""<br />3826961-2 (SV): ""<br />3826984-1 (NE): ""<br />3826986-2 (SV): ""<br />3826987-1 (SV): ""<br />3827041-1 (NE): ""<br />3827055-1 (NE): ""<br />3827076-3 (NE): ""<br />3827093-5 (SV): ""<br />3827160-2 (SV): ""<br />3840124-3 (SV): ""<br />M83248-1-145 (NE): ""<br />M83248-1-145 (NE): ""<br />S8990-167 (NE): ""<br />S8990-276 (NE): ""<br />S8990-605 (NE): ""</span>



        </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```
BODY, TH, TD, DIV, SPAN, P {
    font-size:11px;
}

#VandaagLijst {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}


#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
    border:solid 1px #999999;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;

    width:918px;height:14px;margin:2px;
}


/**
PRINT VERSION
**/


#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span {
    display:table;
    float:left;
    font-size:11px;
    height:14px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:75px;
    border:solid 1px red;

}

#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span.Pn {    

    font-weight:bold;
}
#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span.Description {

    overflow:hidden;
}
#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span.RemarksAction {
    display:none;
}



#VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span.Shortages {
    width:160px;
    background-color:White;
    overflow:visible;
}


/**
PRINT VERSION
**/
```

Comment: I think, it's better to use tables here ;-)

Comment: Table not an option, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `height:auto;` on .WorkorderBlock span.bigger

---

edit after new code above

remove the `height:14px` from #VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock

remove the `height:14px` and `display:table` from #VandaagLijst div.WorkorderBlock span

Comment: This actually does it! Best answer for my problem! Fits exactly into my application. Thanks a lot.

Comment: All spans are actually labels containing values. They are absolutely positioned within the block, except for the view where I had problems. This is a print-view where the spans should really just act like a table. But the table was no (perfect) solution for my problem, i really needed to transform the block layout with spans to a table. So best solution!

Answer (score 1):

give display:table property to all span.
need more play with width.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shouldn't use floating spans.

If a block (span or div) is floated; it is taken out of the normal flow, that is, its size no longer counts towards the size of the containing block. Using relative position is probably best in your case.

Reading (parts of) [the CSS 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) might be a good investment of your time.

Comment: I was assuming it wasn't true because the other solution DOES work. I'll take away the downvote sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn is right about the float's height not being counted.

However, there is a work-around:

```
<div id="9142" class="WorkorderBlock">
        <span class="Workorder">S100580</span>
        <span class="Pn">3616960-2</span>
        ...
        ...
        <span class="bigger">3616967-1<br />3616967-1<br />
                             3616967-1<br />3616967-1<br />3616967-1<br /></span>        
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE the div with style "clear:both" at the end of each WorkorderBlock div. It will mitigate the effect of the spans' heights not being counted.

But I must strongly suggest the use of tables: this is what tables are made for!

Cheers!

Comment: I understand it looks as if tables are the solution here. But I NEED floating spans 2/3 of the apps duration, the "table-view" is only needed 1/3.

Comment: is that correct? that could be because spans are inline elements, not block elements... It could work as expected with divs instead of spans...